# .bashrc saves previous process id and does not update in alias commands

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I have made an alias in .bashrc to kill my `python service.py &` process

```
alias servicestop="kill $(ps -ef | grep -w service.py  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')"
```

Whenever I run first time `servicestop` command it will kill the process. 
but again whenever I start process `python service.py &`, and execute command `servicestop` it gives an error.

After research, I found following things.
when I run first time  `python service.py &` process. its process id was `512`.
and, command `servicestop` kill that process(512).

Now when I run Second time process  `python service.py &`. its process id was 546.(definitely it will be different).

When I run command `servicestop`. it will give following error:

```
-bash: kill: (512) - No such process
```

That means `$(ps -ef | grep -w service.py  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')` will return the previous pid, which is already killed.
Now please suggest the solution if any possible.

so whenever I want to run `servicestop` command, I have to run `source .bashrc` command first, then run  `servicestop` command to make it work.

Comment: You need to use functions, because this string evaluates only once at start

Comment: can you give the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the `servicestop` alias from your `.bashrc` and add :

```
servicestop(){
  kill $(ps -ef | grep -w service.py  | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}');
}
```

*In a way, functions in .bashrc are "aliases 2.0" : simply better*

---

**Better** : same function; but with the name of script to kill as parameter :

```
servicestop(){
  kill $(ps -ef | grep -w $1  | grep -v servicestop | awk '{print $2}');
}
```

Use it like that :

```
servicestop service.py

servicestop otherSuperService.py
```

Comment: Answer inspired by @Sergius

Comment: I have suggested few changes in answer but not updated

Comment: I cannot see your suggestions - don't hesitate to add another comment so that I can make the necessary changes

Comment: Remove $1 at the end of kill command. it is not neccessary.  I have removed it and now it not gives any error.

Comment: Why not directly use `pgrep` instead of `ps -ef` ?

Comment: Also Use [grep regex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results) to make command much better like this `ps -ef | grep [s]ervices.py`